# Есть ли в предложении противопоставление?

Tags: стилистика

*Не важно какой он: некрасивый или неуродливый — он должен сделать это.*

Являются ли противопоставлением слова *некрасивый* и *неуродливый?*

Answer (score 1):

«Неважно какой он». Сам текст не противопоставляет. Слово *неважно* (пишется слитно) имеет синоним «безразлично». Слово *некрасивый* (один из синонимов: *уродливый*) пишется слитно; слова «*неуродливый*» не существует, возможен только раздельный вариант: *не уродливый*, а невзрачный; уродливый или *не уродливый*.

Comment: После "не важно" нет запятой. Это правильно или нет?

Comment: Предложение, неполное и краткое, не делил бы запятой, хотя примеров деления достаточно. Так же, как с раздельным написанием *не важно* без явного противопоставления. Грань часто смазаной бывает.